# Ideal of the Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Show that an ideal $(m)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal if and only if $m$ is prime.

I know that if $m$ is a prime number. And $\mathbb{Z}/m$ is a field and thus $m$ is maximal. 
I know i have to do a prove both direction for if and only if statement.

Comment: Suppose $m = ab$ and show that $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ cannot be an integral domain

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $m$ is composite, and let $q$ be any non-trivial factor of $m$.  Then $(m) \subset (q)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, suppose $m$ is not prime. If $m=1$, then $(m)=\mathbb{Z}$, which is not maximal. Now if $m\neq 1$, $\exists a,b\neq 0$ such that $ab=m$. Then $a+(m), b+(m)\neq (m)$, but $(a+(m))(b+(m))=ab+(m)=0+(m)$, so $\mathbb{Z}/(m)$ is not an integral domain (and in particular, not a field). Hence $(m)$ is not maximal (by the fact that a proper ideal of a nonzero commutative ring is maximal if and only if the quotient ring is a field).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if $\,a,b,m\in\Bbb Z\;$ , then in $\;\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\;\;:\;(a+m\Bbb Z)(b+m\Bbb Z)=ab+m\Bbb Z\;$ .

Also, a commutative unitary ring is a field iff every non-zero element in it has a multiplicative inverse, so:

$$\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\;\;\text{is a field}\;\iff \;\forall\,a\notin m\Bbb Z\;\exists\, b\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t.\;\;ab+m\Bbb Z=1+m\Bbb Z\;\iff$$

$$\iff\;\forall\;a\in\Bbb Z\;\;s.t.\;m\nmid a\;\;\exists\,b,x\in\Bbb Z\;\;\text{with}\;\;ab+mx=1\iff \;g.c.d(a,m)=1\,\iff$$

$$\iff\;\neg\exists\;a\in\Bbb Z\,,\,\,1\le a<m\;\;s.t.\;\;a\mid m\iff m\;\;\text{is prime}$$